# complete DAGs extends every non-complete DAG over the same vertex set

Tags: graph-theory

Given a set of vertices $V$ and a directed acyclic graph $G(V,E)$, is it always possible to extend $G$ to a tournament (a complete DAG over V) ?

My intuition is yes: Get the undirected graph of $G$ and add edges to form complete undirected graph. Then add orientations to the added edges such that the complete graph is acyclic.  Another intuition is that every DAG give a rise to a partial order and every partial order can be extended to a total order.

Is this correct? Any pointer to read more about this is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Just find a [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of $G$, say $u_1,\ldots,u_n$, and for every edge *not* in $G$, say $(u_i,u_j)$, with $i<j$, add it in and orient it from $u_i$ to $u_j$. The resulting tournament is still going to be acyclic.

Answer (score 1):

The "Then add orientations ...acyclic" is too vague I think: it's not so obvious that this can be done.  The proof using partial orders is correct.